# fetching data from JSON causes crash

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I try to fetch a single String from a JSON file.

This file uses data, which is stored in a MySql Database.

The following logcat shows the problem:

```
09-03 20:05:04.825: E/pass 1(27476): connection success 
09-03 20:05:04.825: E/pass 2(27476): connection success 
09-03 20:05:04.830: E/Fail 3(27476): org.json.JSONException: Value 29 of type       

java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I know that this error was solved in many questions on Stackoverflow and I tried all solutions:

1. Use UTF-8 in every document
2. substring() every string
3. ...

Meanwhile I think this is a "code" problem, something must be wrong.

All the code parts are from this tutorial:

[tutorial](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php)

Please have a look at:

Android Activity:

```
   > try
    {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myserver/msqlup.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
 }
     catch(Exception e)
 {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
    {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
         String name=(json_data.getString("$new"));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : "+name,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}
```

msqlup.php

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$uname='myname';
$pwd='mypw';
$db="mydb";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");



$r=mysql_query("SELECT Coins from table WHERE new= 1234567");
 $abfrage = "
SELECT
 Coins
FROM
 lunation";


$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage) OR die(mysql_error());


while($zeile = mysql_fetch_assoc($ergebnis)){
 $new=$zeile["Coins"];

  }

 print(json_encode($new));


 ?>
```

**And this is what I want to do:
1. Get Value of "Coins" from database "table"
2. save it in Android Activity using a String**

I am grateful for any advice (:

Comment: In java code print out `result` and see what wonders you have there.

Comment: Okay, Logcat shows "29", and thats exactly what it should be..

Comment: Change `Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());` for         `Log.e("result: ", resul);`

Comment: Sorry, but it is "29", but the left quote has another style then the right quote o.0

Comment: That tutorial is terrible. None of the parameters are  parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and it's full of [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$new=$zeile["Coins"];
```

to

```
$new = $zeile;
```

Then in your java to read this you need to:

```
String name = json_data.getString("Coins");
```

Also make sure that the response received is `"Coins" : "29"` not `"Coins" : 29`.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear your `result` variable is not a valid `JSONObject` as it simply contains the `String` "29".

In PHP `json_encode` only really works on objects and arrays, so I would add your `$new` variable to an object or array and then on the Android client,  either create a `new JSONObject(result)` or `new JSONArray(result)` depending on the data structure you chose to `json_encode`

Comment: $zeile is in fact a php object, which is why it works :)